# Simple calendar using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to write all the dates, days and months of 2019 in JavaScript. By using 3 functions. I only found 1 function I could use but I don't get it to work out. Anyone have some ideas or tips? Thanks.

I need a function of NameOfTheMonths, NameOfTheWeekdays and DaysInAMonth. One function of each. No prints should be present in functions, all prints should be made in connection with the iterations.

```
document.writeln("Days in 2019 is:");

var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

for (var i = 0; i<=months.length; i++)
{
    for (var k = 1; k<=31; k++)
    {
        document.write(months[i]);
        document.writeln(k);

    }
}
function rightAdjust(x, size)
{
    x = "" + x; // secure that x is a string

    var noOfBlanks = size - x.length;
    var blanks = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfBlanks; i++)
    {
        blanks = blanks + " ";
    }

    return blanks + x;
}
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var days; 
days = DaysInAMonth(k);

for (var i = 0; i<=months.length; i++){

    for (var k = 1; k<=days.length; k++)
    {
        document.write(months[i]);
        document.writeln(days);

    }
    }

    function DaysInAMonth(days)
    {
        var result; 

         if (months == [0])
        {
            return 31;
        }
        else if (months == [1])
        {
            return 28;
        }
        else if (months == [2])
        {
            return 31;
        }
        else if (months == [3])
        { 
            return 30;
        }
        else if (months == [4])
        {
            return 31;
        }
        else if (months == [5])
        {
            return 30;
        }
        else if (months == [6])
        {
            return 31;
        }
        else if (months == [7])
        {
            return 31;
        }
        else if (months == [8])
        {
            return 30;
        }
        else if (months == [9])
        {
            return 31;
        }
        else if (months == [10])
        {
            return 30;
        }
        else if (months == [11])
        {
            return 31;
        }
    }
    document.write(DaysInAMonth(1));
```

Comment: What should those three functions return, and which arguments would they need to get? Did you get a template for them?

Comment: do your homework without cheating! ;-)

Comment: Didn't get a template. I am not sure what you mean by which arguments they need to get. Sorry! :/

Comment: I mean, you could just create three empty functions that take no arguments and return nothing, and do all the work outside of them. Obviously that is not what you are looking for. So could you describe what those three functions need to return? If you don't know, then how can we?

Comment: Wouldn't call it cheating. Not studying anything with programming but I need to understand it. Will have an oral exam in this so do not worry.

Comment: Right! The function DaysInAMonth are going to give me the days, from 1 to 31. NameOfTheMonths are going to give me the name of all the months in a year. NameOfTheWeekdays all the days from monday to sunday. Although all these are going to result in e.g: Monday, 1st, January.

Comment: I don't get it. You already have the names of the months in an array. What would a function add to that? What you describe are arrays, not functions.

Comment: A function DaysInAMonth should be and be used in the solution. The function should have a parameter that specifies an order number for the month and should return the number of days in the current month as a number. A function NameOfTheWeekdays should be available and used in the solution. The function should have a parameter that specifies an order number for a weekday and returns the current name as a string. NameOfTheMonths should be present and used in the solution. The function should have a parameter that specifies an order number for a month and returns the month's name as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript I would just use an object.

```
obj = {months:[
  {name: "january", days: 31},
  {name: "febuary", days: 28},
  {name: "march", days: 31},
  {name: "april", days: 30},
    ...
]}
```

and do some nested `forEach()` and `for` loops on the object with an array of weekday names and MOD on the array index of weekday names.

```
printyear(firstdayindex = 0) {
  let days = ["mon","tues", "wed"....]
  let currentday = firstdayindex;
  obj.months.forEach((m) => {
     for (int x = 1; x <= m.days; x++) { console.log(days[(currentday++)%7]+ x + m.name) }
  })
}
```

But if you really want to abstract out into these functions, I am sure you can do something like this:

```
NameOfTheMonths() {
  let names = [];
  obj.months.forEach(m => {names.push(m.name);
  return names;})
}

NameOfTheWeekdays() {//just return an array of names }

DaysInAMonth(month) {obj.months.findIndex(m=>m.name===month).days}
```

With more information on specifically what they should do I could probably add more but i would personally go about the task without those 3 functions and just operate on the object I describe above since the only input you would need is what day of the week the first day of the year is. Then you will have to do more work to piece the data back together from the 3 functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I will try this!

Comment: I edited the answer because that is an object literal, not JSON. [There is not such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: sure, it is just colloquial terminology